# Dynamically Setting Row height in Tableview works on some cells only

Tags: uitableview, swift, row-height

I have a table view where rows are populated with data from an array.
Row height is set dynamically in viewDidLoad() by calling this function:

```
func configureTableView() {          
    /*  When you set the rowHeight as UITableViewAutomaticDimension, the table view knows to use the auto layout constraints to determine each cell’s height. This also reuqires a estimetedRowHeoght, an arbitary number */      
    println("Configure Table View called")

   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 74.0;
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
}
```

The data to populate each row is loading into arrays aysnrounscly from Parse.
Once data is loaded into arrays I then call:

```
self.tableView.reloadData();

self.configureTableView();
```

... in order to reload table row data and then re-conguire the row height dynamically, according to size of comments populating  label within a row.

Problem is two fold:

1. Only some rows have the height set dynamically, other rows the row height appears to be fixed you can't view the comments if more than one line
2. When user scrolls the tableview, the refreshed view all rows are static, none appear to have height set dynamically, only one line of comment can be seen.

Any input appreciated

I am also using a footer view which is created programmictally with code to allow fro showing and hiding the keyboard, i think this may of something to do with it ....

// viewDidlOad

```
 /* Setup the keyboard notifications  so does not block textview for adding comments */
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


        /* Setup the contentInsets fo keyboard  */
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero


        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
        /* Make sure the content doesn't go below tabbar/navbar */
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Apologies in advance but Allot of code here for setting up footer view and handling user input....

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


        footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: FOOTERHEIGHT))
        footerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 243.0/255, green: 243.0/255, blue: 243.0/255, alpha: 1)
        commentView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: tableView.bounds.width - 80 , height: 40))
        commentView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        commentView?.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
        commentView?.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        commentView?.scrollsToTop = true

        footerView?.addSubview(commentView!)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.bounds.width - 65, y: 10, width: 60 , height: 30))
        button.setTitle("Reply", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 155.0/255, green: 189.0/255, blue: 113.0/255, alpha: 1)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.addTarget(self, action: "reply", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        footerView?.addSubview(button)
        commentView?.delegate = self

        return footerView

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {


        if self.footerView != nil {
            return self.footerView!.bounds.height
        }
        return FOOTERHEIGHT


    func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

        // Called in viewDidlOad, make sure keyoard doe snot cover add comments textview in table voew footer

        var info:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()

        var keyboardHeight:CGFloat =  keyboardSize.height - 40

        var animationDuration:CGFloat = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as CGFloat

        var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0);
        self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    }

    func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

        //As above

        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }


    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

        // Allow for dynamic changing if TableView Footer textview size when commenst added

        if (contentHeight == 0) {
            contentHeight = commentView!.contentSize.height
        }

        if(commentView!.contentSize.height != contentHeight && commentView!.contentSize.height > footerView!.bounds.height) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
                let myview = self.footerView
                println(self.commentView!.contentSize.height)
                println(self.commentView?.font.lineHeight)
                let newHeight : CGFloat = self.commentView!.font.lineHeight
                let myFrame = CGRect(x: myview!.frame.minX, y: myview!.frame.minY - newHeight , width: myview!.bounds.width, height: newHeight + myview!.bounds.height)
                myview?.frame = myFrame

                let mycommview = self.commentView
                let newCommHeight : CGFloat = self.commentView!.contentSize.height
                let myCommFrame = CGRect(x: mycommview!.frame.minX, y: mycommview!.frame.minY, width: mycommview!.bounds.width, height: newCommHeight)
                mycommview?.frame = myCommFrame

                self.commentView = mycommview
                self.footerView  = myview

                for item in self.footerView!.subviews {
                    if(item.isKindOfClass(UIButton.self)){
                        let button = item as UIButton
                        let newY = self.footerView!.bounds.height / 2 - button.bounds.height / 2
                        let buttonFrame = CGRect(x: button.frame.minX, y: newY , width: button.bounds.width, height : button.bounds.height)
                        button.frame = buttonFrame

                    }
                }
            })

            println(self.footerView?.frame)
            println(self.commentView?.frame)
            contentHeight = commentView!.contentSize.height
        }


    }


    func reply() {

        // When Add button clicked in custom TabkeView Footer

        println("User added comment: \(commentView?.text)");

        self.commentView?.resignFirstResponder()


        //userComments = commentView!.text;

        //addComment();


        self.tableView.reloadData()

        //self.configureTableView();
    }
```

Comment: Try using this code. 
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            tableView.reloadData()
    }

Comment: Thanks yes have that still same, i am also using a footer view created programmatically to allow for adding comments, might have something to do with this, i will ad to question

Comment: When I last used dynamic rowheight, I also had to override another tableView function heightforrowatindexpath. In this you simply return the height

Comment: Thanks but still the same

Comment: If you are using different heights for different cells, then make the decision based on indexPath of the function parameter.

Comment: Gave up and started from scratch, works now not sure what the issue was, maybe a layout problem